# "Promote" generic type to Nullable in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, metaprogramming, nullable, type-traits

Given a generic type `T` in C#, I wonder how to acquire type `Q`, which is equal to `T?` for non-nullable `T`, and `T` for already nullable `T`.

The question arose from real code. I want to unify access to parameters passed through query string in my ASP.NET application. And I want to specify a default value of the same type, but ensure `null` can be passed as a default value.

```
public static T FetchValue<T>(
   string name, 
   <T? for non-nullable, T otherwise> default_value = null)  // How to write this?
{
  var page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;

  string str = page.Request.QueryString[name];

  if (str == null)
  {
    if (default_value == null)
    {
      throw new HttpRequestValidationException("A " + name + " must be specified.");
    }
    else
    {
      return default_value;
    }
  }

  return (T)Convert.ChangeType(str, typeof(T));
}
```

Currently I'm forced having two overloads of the `FetchValue` - one without default value, and one with it:

```
public static T FetchValue<T>(string name);
public static T FetchValue<T>(string name, T default_value);
```

It works fine, but I wonder whether it is possible to merge both functions like this.

In C++ I would use type-traits, like `PromoteNullable<T>::type` with two specializations of `PromoteNullable` for both nullable and non-nullable types. But what about C#?

Comment: I personally think the code is clearer from the call site if you just have two overloads.

Comment: @MatthewWatson The code from the call site is _exactly the same_ for both implementations.

Comment: The compiler would struggle to generate suitable code for `return default_value;` if `default_value` was this "maybe a `T`, maybe a `T?`" type. Even `return (T)default_value;` needs different code if it's a `T?`. Remember, the compiler has to generate one piece of code that is suitable for all instantiations.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever What do you mean the generated code would be the same for different instantiations?.. That's not true for C++ templates. Is that true for C# generics?

Comment: C# generics are a runtime feature, not a compile time feature as in C++'s templates. As such, the compiler has to generate *one* sequence of IL that will be valid for any supplied type parameter. (There is some variation in how that IL is translated to machine code at JIT time, based on value/reference types, but the IL is always the same)

Comment: As another side note - I'd probably go with the two overloads, but have a private internal method `bool TryFetchValue<T>(string name,ref T value)` that both call. It does the dirty work, then all the `FetchValue` methods have to do is either return the default value or throw an exception (depending on which overload they are)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I didn't know that, thanks. Concerning `TryFetchValue` - this is how I actually implemented this :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesn't directly answer the question as posed, but I'd write this:

```
    public static T FetchValue<T>(string name)
    {
        T value;
        if (TryFetchValue(name, out value))
            return value;
        throw new HttpRequestValidationException("A " + name + " must be specified.");
    }

    public static T FetchValue<T>(string name, T default_value)
    {
        T value;
        if (TryFetchValue(name, out value))
            return value;
        return default_value;
    }

    private static bool TryFetchValue<T>(
         string name,
         out T value)
    {
        var page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;

        string str = page.Request.QueryString[name];

        if (str == null)
        {
            value = default(T);
            return false;
        }

        value = (T)Convert.ChangeType(str, typeof(T));
        return true;
    }
```

So the bulk of the code exists only once - and you can even now actually have the calling code choose to have `null` as a default value, if it so chooses.

---

Even if you could create the parameter declaration you wanted, this line would still be an issue:

```
return default_value;
```

If it turned out that `default_value` was a `T?` rather than a `T`, then the above code doesn't work. Even if you do a cast:

```
return (T)default_value;
```

there's still an issue - that to cast from `T?` to `T`, the compiler actually has to insert a call to obtain the `Value` property of the nullable. But that call wouldn't be valid if the type of `default_value` was just `T`.

In C# Generics, the compiler has to create one piece of IL for the method. There's no way to insert an optional piece of code that *may* access `Value`.

Comment: That's almost how it is currently implemented :)

Comment: Ok, I didn't receive an answer to my question, but I have an explanation why there is no answer. Thanks, I accept this.

Answer (score 1):

Since your return type is `T`, and `T` beeing a value type, it can't be null.
So you'll always have to pass a nullable type, since you want a null back, right?

Try this one, it allows you to pass a nullable value type (`i`) and a normal reference type (`o`):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int? i = 5;
    object x = new object();

    object o = FetchValue("x", i);
    o = FetchValue("x", x);
}

private static T? FetchValue<T>(string name, T? p) where T : struct
{
    T? result = (T?)FetchValue(name, (object)p);
    return result;
}

private static T FetchValue<T>(string name,
    T default_value = default (T)) // default(T) where T is a reference type will always be null!
    where T : class
{
    // do whatever you want
    var page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;

    string str = page.Request.QueryString[name];

    if (str == null)
    {
        if (default_value == null)
        {
            throw new HttpRequestValidationException("A " + name + " must be specified.");
        }
        else
        {
            return default_value;
        }
    }

    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(str, typeof(T));
}
```

Please keep in mind that's all syntax foo, since you'll end up with an `object` type for T anyway. This however is required, since only `object`'s are able to be null.

Comment: In this case I cannot use `FetchValue<int>("x")` without default value. I don't want a `null` back, I want a default value, or an exception.

Comment: When using `FetchValue<int>("x")` and having a return type of T you can't get null back since `int` is not a reference type. When talking about `default_value` I tought you always want a reference/nullable type back. (What of course does not very mutch sence, since you would use `object` as the return type then)

Answer (score 1):

There is my example:

```
//Page extension
static class PageExtensions
{
    private static T FetchValue<T>(this Page page, string name, object defaultValue)
    {
        string str = page.Request.QueryString[name];
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
        {
            if (defaultValue != null)
                return (T)defaultValue;

            throw new HttpRequestValidationException("A " + name + " must be specified.");
        }

        //not the best way
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(str, typeof(T));
    }

    public static T FetchValueFromCurrentPage<T>(string name, T defaultValue)
    { 
      var page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;
      if(page == null)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Current handler is not Page");
      return page.FetchValue<T>(name, defaultValue);
    }

    public static T FetchValueFromCurrentPage<T>(string name) where T : class
    {   
        return FetchValueFromCurrentPage(name, (T)null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice thought about making an extension function. But the `FetchValue` itself is not type-safe, e.g. one may call `FetchValue<int>("id", "foo")`, and it will compile.

Comment: Also I don't understand why `FetchValue` and `FetchValueFromCurrentPage` don't have symmetric prototypes. It is impossible to use structs without default values for the latter, like this: `PageExtensions.FetchValueFromCurrentPage<int>("id")`.

Comment: I think, that you need something like 'return default(T)' in case of T is ValueType. And in your example: null value can't be default value - it's not good practice. I want return null value as default value for example.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
private static T FetchValue<T>(string name, Nullable<T> default_value = null) where T : struct
{
    var page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;

    string str = page.Request.QueryString[name];

    if (str == null)
    {
        if (default_value == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("A " + name + " must be specified.");
        }
        else
        {
            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(default_value, typeof(T));
        }
    }

    return default(T);
}
```

Nullable types must be a value type and so you must set the constraint to `struct`. You're declaring type `T` as `Nullable` and converting the type if there is a value else you return the `default` of type `T` which in this case is null. When calling this method you must also set the type explicitly like so:

```
int? val = FetchValue<int>("name");
```

**Returning a string**

As a `string` is a nullable reference type you correctly say that it can't be used with this function. In that case I would create a new `struct` and for strings use this instead.

```
struct NullableString
{
    public string Value;
}
```

Call the function like this.

```
var val = FetchValue<NullableString>("blah", new NullableString() { Value = "default" });
```

Comment: I do want this function to work with nullable types, at least with strings.

Comment: This obfuscates code on the caller site, so I don't think it is practical. Nice thought to wrap `string` in `struct` though.

Comment: @Mikhail I suppose you could have the calls to this function proxied, so in the event of a string type being passed it will wrap up in this struct. But I agree, it'll start getting very messy from there on.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the *class* constraint to make sure callers pass in a reference type (which is nullable):

```
public static T FetchValue<T>(
   string name, 
   T default_value = null) where T : class //!
{
  var page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;

  string str = page.Request.QueryString[name];

  if (str == null)
  {
    if (default_value == null)
    {
      throw new HttpRequestValidationException("A " + name + " must be specified.");
    }
    else
    {
      return default_value;
    }
  }

  return (T)Convert.ChangeType(str, typeof(T));
}
```

In this case, you delegate the responsibility of casting T to T? when necessary to the caller, which is nice anyway: he may know better!

Comment: Same as for @Terric - I really want both nullable and non-nullable (class ans structs) types allowed. At least `int`s and `string`s.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want in this simple way:

```
public static T FetchValue<T>(string name, T defaultValue = null) where T : class { }
public static T? FetchValue<T>(string name, T? defaultValue = null) where T : struct { }
```

Comment: This requires two overloads, while I already have solution with two overloads, which I find easier.

Comment: @Mikhail it is the simpliest and the most efficient way to go.